# How to step through a longjmp in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, setjmp

I'm trying to fix a bug in code someone else wrote, and I'm trying to step though it in gdb to figure out what is going on. But one of the lines I hit is a call to longjmp(), and after hitting "next" on that line gdb continues regular execution rather than breaking on the next source line being executed. Similar continue occurs if I try "step" on the longjmp() line. Is there any gdb command I can use to break on the next source line being executed after longjmp()?

Comment: You could do `break main`, then `run` and keep `step`ping through the program. Then it would prompt for input at every line, including the one after longjmp(). (If that answered your question i'll put it in an answer)

Comment: What happens if you hit "step" on that line instead of "next"? One thing you could do is add a breakpoint on the code that handles a non-zero return value from `setjmp()`.

Comment: @MDXF, to be clear, is your point to use the `step` command instead of the `next` command?  The OP says that doesn't work for him.  I see that you suggest specifically breaking at `main`, but I don't see why that would make a difference vs. breaking somewhere else, prior to the `longjmp()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a breakpoint at the line following a non-zero return code by `setjmp`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf jb;

void f1()
{
    printf("jumping\n");
    longjmp(jb, 1);
    printf("what???\n");
}

int main()
{
    if (!setjmp(jb)) {
        printf("calling f1\n");
        f1();
    } else {
        printf("jumped!!\n");    // line 19
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After calling `longjmp`, the next line to be executed is line 19 (see comment).  So in this case run `break 19` at the gdb prompt and you'll stop at that line after the call to `longjmp`.

gdb output:

```
(gdb) break 19
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40056d: file /tmp/x1.c, line 19.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 3 at 0x400549: file /tmp/x1.c, line 15.
Starting program: /tmp/x1
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000

Temporary breakpoint 3, main () at /tmp/x1.c:15
15          if (!setjmp(jb)) {
(gdb) step
16              printf("calling f1\n");
(gdb)
calling f1
17              f1();
(gdb)
f1 () at /tmp/x1.c:8
8           printf("jumping\n");
(gdb)
jumping
9           longjmp(jb, 1);
(gdb)

Breakpoint 2, main () at /tmp/x1.c:19
19              printf("jumped!!\n");
(gdb)
jumped!!
21          return 0;
(gdb)
22      }
(gdb)
0x0000003fa441d9f4 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Comment: This basically worked. It took a little bit of searching to figure out what setjmp was the last one called, but after putting breakpoints after the non-zero return of enough setjmps I eventually figured out where the program was going.

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that gdb's behavior is system-dependent.

On Linux, `next` over a `longjmp` or `throw` works approximately as you would expect: if the target of the non-local jump is at or above the current frame, execution will stop there.

This is implemented using debugging hooks in the implementations of `longjmp` and `throw`.  For `throw` this is done both with a helper function (the older approach) and with so-called SystemTap probes (aka "sdt probes").  For `longjmp` this is done only with sdt probes in glibc.

For this to work the probe support must be compiled into the libraries in question.  You can check with `readelf -n`.  At least Fedora does this properly.

It's possible in theory to implement support for `longjmp` for other platforms in gdb.  However, it may be non-trivial.

You can try to decode the `jmp_buf`, as mentioned in other comments.  Note however that on some systems, such as Linux, the target PC in the `jmp_buf` is encoded, for security reasons.  So you will have to figure out how to decode it.

Another way to approach this is to simply single-step through `longjmp` itself.  Set a breakpoint there, like `break longjmp`; use `disassemble` to view the assembly; and then `si` until you step through the instruction that transfers execution to the target.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any gdb command I can use to break on the next source line being executed after longjmp()?

Not as far as I know, no.  You'll need to trace the origin of the `jmp_buf` back up the call stack to find the `setjmp()` by which it was filled.  If `setjmp()` calls in the source are few, you might consider setting a breakpoint after each.  Otherwise, you might just step through the program, setting a breakpoint after each `setjmp()` you pass.

Note also that you indeed should find the relevant `setjmp()` in one of the functions in the call stack when the corresponding `longjmp()` is reached, for otherwise the `jmp_buf` is invalid.

You can use the `bt` command to get a call stack, and the `frame` command to switch to and inspect any frame on the stack.